Adding multiple parameters to Cosmos DB query
I'm creating a wrapper for Cosmos DB client using the new Cosmos DB SDK for .NET.
In this example, I see how I add a single parameter to a query: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/quickstart-dotnet?pivots=devcontainer-codespace#query-items
In my generic wrapper method, I may get multiple parameters or none at all. I don't see an Add() option for adding parameters to a query after it was defined. How do I add multiple parameters to a Cosmos DB query?
Here's my generic wrapper method:
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> ReadQuery<T>(string sql, Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
{
   var query = new Query(sql);

   if(parameters != null && parameters.Count > 0)
      foreach(var item in parameters)
         ??? // How do I add parameters to my query here?

   using FeedIterator<T> feed = container.GetItemQueryIterator<T>(
    queryDefinition: query
    );
}


Use the QueryDefinition class to build your SQL query in Cosmos DB. Add parameters using the WithParameter method in a loop for each key-value pair in your dictionary.
